# Sorting dataframe rows by Day of Date wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have made my dataframe. But I want to sort it by the date wise..For example, I want data for 02.01.2016 just after 01.01.2016.

```
df_data_2311 = df_data_231.groupby('Date').agg({'Wind Offshore in [MW]': ['sum']})
df_data_2311 = pd.DataFrame(df_data_2311)
```

After running this, I got the below output. This dataframe has 2192 rows.

```
    Wind Offshore in [MW]
sum
Date    
01.01.2016  5249.75
01.01.2017  12941.75
01.01.2018  19020.00
01.01.2019  13723.00
01.01.2020  17246.25
... ...
31.12.2017  21322.50
31.12.2018  13951.75
31.12.2019  21457.25
31.12.2020  16491.25
31.12.2021  35683.25
```

Kindly let me know How would I sort this data of the day of the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) function in pandas.

```
df_data_2311.sort_values(by=["Date"])
```

However in order to sort them by the `Date` column you will need `reset_index()` on your grouped dataframe and then to convert the date values to datetime, you can use [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```
df_data_2311 = df_data_231.groupby('Date').agg({'Wind Offshore in [MW]': ['sum']}).reset_index()
df_data_2311["Date"] = pandas.to_datetime(df_data_2311["Date"], format="%d.%m.%Y")
df_data_2311 = df_data_2311.sort_values(by=["Date"])
```

I recommend reviewing the pandas docs.